# Shellscript - Log of mv files

Tags: bash, shell, logging, mv

Im writing a script to use as a sort of Recycle Bin to delete and restore files.
When calling the 'del' script I can specify a file using a wildcard, full filepath, or just a filename.

For the restoring I think I'll need a log file to store the original locations from where they were "deleted" using mv

To create the log file I am using code

```
# echo $path >> /root/Dustbin/log.txt
```

This works fine when I specify the entire path for deleting `

```
# del /root/A_Folder/Afile.txt
```

However I need a way to store the entire filepath when I only delete it using

```
# del afile.txt
```

Is there anyway to retreive the path of the file when I delete it as such?

Hope that makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recomemed you to keep full path of files inside your 'Recycle Bin' instead of a log file. This is better because you can mv files with same filename but in a another folder, you not need to keep update your log file when you remove definitely

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out - I could save the full filepath using the code below:

```
readlink -f $path >> /root/Dustbin/log.txt
```